# How do I set a start time for a zoompan filter that overlays a video background in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The below code works fine but I cannot seem to succeed at starting this image zoom at a specific time. i.e I want the zoom to be effective at 5 seconds not immediately when the background video starts.

```
ffmpeg  -i background.avi  -i image.png \
-filter_complex "1:v]scale=8000x4000,setsar=1/1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.005,10)':d=125:s=530x680,trim=duration=3[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=20:20" \
-c:v libx264 output.avi
```

Comment: I was going to say you need to add `enable='gte(t,5)'` to the options, but then it'll probably jump in the image.

Comment: @slhck yes you are right, that's what happens I've tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg  -i background.avi -loop 1 -i image.png \
  -filter_complex 
       "[1:v]scale=8000x4000,setsar=1/1,zoompan=z='if(gte(in,125),min(pzoom+0.005,10),1)':d=1:s=530x680,
            trim=duration=3[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=20:20"
  -c:v libx264 output.avi
```

Since you're applying this on a video, pzoom is the correct variable to use. `d` should be set to 1 since it represents the duration of the zoom effect interval for each **individual** frame. Be sure to use a recent ffmpeg version. There was a bug in earlier versions where pzoom did not function correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mulvya. I 1stly downloaded the recent version(3.3.1) before trying your command out and this is the error that I get:  " Unknown function in 't,5),min(pzoom+0.005,10),1)'
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
    Last message repeated 1 times
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0"

Comment: Oops. One has to use in frame count, which is `time x fps`. Edited answer.

Comment: The error is gone however, the image does not zoom in

Comment: Increase the trim duration to a value greater than 5